# Clothoid parallel to clothoid

Tags: analytic-geometry

I wanted to ask the question "Can clothoids be made parallel with other clothoids" I have come across statements that this is not possible, but no proof. A previous poster ["Jean Marie"](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/305862/jean-marie) [states that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886309/parallel-clothoid-parameters#comment3867881_1886309):

> "You may know that in general, parallel curves of non-polynomial curves have no explicit equation"

seems to corroborate this (clothoid is transcendental). I am using clothoids in the alignment of bridge decks. The offsets from the setting out line or "Master String" should be parallel to the Master String. I have gotten around this problem by generating coordinates along the offsets perpendicular to the clothoid and fitting a third order polynomial to the data using "Linest". This gives satisfactory results, however I would like to see a proof of "clothoids can not be made parallel to other clothoids" Can anyone supply this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
s \mapsto C(s)
$$
be a clothoid with $C(0) = (0,0), C'(0) = (1, 0)$, and $k_C(s) = s$, and $s$ is an arclength parameter, just to make things very explicit. Let $N(s)$ be the (oriented) unit normal to $C$ at $C(s)$, so that $N(0) = (0, 1)$. Let's look at the offset curve of $C$, along $N$, but distance $1$. That's 
$$
t \mapsto D(t) = C(t) + N(t)
$$
where I've used $t$ to remind us that $D$ is *not* in general parameterized by arclength. Let's compute a few things. Letting $T(s) = C'(s)$ denote the (unit) tangent vector, and $R$ denote counterclockwise rotation by $\pi/2$, we have

\begin{align}
T'(s) &= k_C(s) N(s) \\
N(s) &= R T(s) \\
R N(s) &= R^2 T(s) = -T(s) \\
N'(s) &= R T'(s) \\
N'(s) &= R (k_C(s)N(s)) = -k_C(s) T(s)\\
N''(s) &= -k_C'(s) T(s) - k_C(s) T'(s)\\
&= -T(s) - s^2 N(s)
\end{align}

That should be enough to get us started. Let's compute $D'(t)$ and $D''(t)$ and see how those look. 
\begin{align}
D'(t) &= C'(t) + N'(t) \\
&= T(t) -k_C(t) T(t)\\
&= (1 -t) T(t)
\end{align}
Actually, right there we have enough. For at $t = 1$, $D(t)$ reverses direction, hence cannot possibly be a clothoid (for the curvature there would have to be infinite).

To summarize: I've shown a (very simple) clothoid, and an offset curve from that clothoid that is *not* a clothoid. Hence in general, it's not true that every offset of a clothoid is itself a clothoid. It's possible that *some* offset of a clothoid is a clothoid -- for instance the zero offset! -- but in general, one cannot be confident that this will happen. 
Indeed, my suspicion is that a nonzero offset from a clothoid is *never* a clothoid, but that might take more work to prove (I think it probably follows with a few more lines from what I've already written down), and it's the answer to a different (and un-asked) question.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, The RL values of the generated polynomials do not come close to being constant, so your point above "my suspicion is that a nonzero offset from a clothoid is never a clothoid" is in agreement with my own findings. If you don't mind I will leave the question open in the hope of an official paper on the subject. I did find a document written by a German professor which stated that Clothoids could not have clothoidal offsets. Unfortunately no proof of this statement was offered.

Comment: In fact, there's an example of a clothoid whose offset curve *is* a clothoid: one for which the rate of increase of curvature is zero. (One might argue that this isn't a clothoid at all; I think that depends on your definition). My guess, however, is that for one whose rate of curvature increase is nonzero, a normalization to make the rate of curvature increase be 1 probably preserves offset curves, so you really only need to look at one case. And to do that, my method above will probably suffice. Rather than looking for someone else to prove it, why not just do it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

A(n attempt at a) qualitative proof.

A clothoid is a curve whose graph of curvature vs length is a straight line. Assume without loss of generality that the curvature is increasing as we go along the clothoid, and the starting curvature is $0$. The curvature at any point is finite. The curvature graph is not bounded from above.

For any point on clothoid, going the offset distance by the normal to the clothoid gets us onto the offset curve; the offset curve's radius of curvature at that point is smaller (second case, *below,* -- greater) in magnitude than the clothoid's radius of curvature, by the value of the offset distance exactly.

For any offset distance, go far enough along the clothoid and you get to the point where the clothoid's radius of curvature has decreased so much that it becomes equal to the offset distance.

The offset line's radius of curvature at this point is $0$. Its curvature is thus infinite. No clothoid has infinite curvature anywhere at a finite arc length, by definition.

In the second case of offset in the other direction, the curvature becomes bounded from above -- the radius of curvature can not become smaller than the offset distance.

[]

Comment: Thanks for the response. The part of the clothoid which is used in roadworks is the tail end, therefore the curvature is small. The application I am looking for does not come anywhere near the eye of the clothoid

Comment: of course. it is nevertheless proves it is not a clothoid, because any clothoid can be extended infinitely -- whether you're using the extended portion or not. so while it is definitely not a clothoid, you might ask *how much* it differs from some clothoid. e.g., you have line, spiral, and circular arc. for the offset, you must offset the line, and the arc by the same distance. then you can ask, what is the clothoid connecting the offset line with the offset arc, and how much does it deviate from the offset clothoid. that is definitely a very different question though.

Comment: (well, maybe not *very* different, but different). for one thing, the connecting clothoid between the offset line and arc will touch the circle at a point which will definitely be *not* opposite the original connection point on the original curve. if you have a software that builds them, run it and see for yourself. :)